# Do we need to use "to" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

I saw the following sentence in a script that includes conversations between a teacher and  students.

> I was looking for ***to*** the question about which Great Lake is the largest.

I do not understand the reason behind using *'to'* here.

Comment: It's not a complete sentence. The full sentence (which I found via Google) is "And do you know why Lake Superior isn't the answer I was looking for to the question about which Great Lake is the largest?" -- It's about the answer (that I was looking for) to the question (about which Great Lake is the largest).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a fragment taken out of context.

Comment: In the future, don't send users scrambling to find the source of your quote. Before asking your next question, I urge you to [read this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have taken this out of its context. The original is:

> And do you know why Lake Superior isn't the answer I was looking for to the question about which Great Lake is the largest?

Here there are two constituents which modify the noun *answer*

> ... the answer [which] I was looking for ...
>   ... the answer ... to the question about which Great Lake is the largest.

The sense is:

> There was a question about which Great Lake is the largest.
>   I was looking for an answer to that question.
>   "Lake Superior" was not that answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the last 'chunk' also include _Do you know why?_ as the last line, for completeness?